# Faithful Representations of C*-algebras

Tags: matrices, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Can anyone give me an example of a represetation of the algebra $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ that is not faithul?
If it's not possible, could you explain me why it is not?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apart from the zero representation, every representation of $M_n$ is faithful. It follows from the fact that [$M_n$ is simple](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654451/for-any-ring-a-the-matrix-ring-m-na-is-simple-if-and-only-if-a-is-simple), meaning it has no non-trivial ideals.