# Endomorphism ring of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have proof of this but not getting please help me.
If $End_{K}(V)$ is a simple ring then $V$ is finite dimensional vector space.
proof:- Let us assume that $V$ be not a finite dimensional vector space over field $K$.
Define 
$I=\{f \in End_{K}(V)\mid\dim_{K}f(V)<\infty\}$
$0 \in I$ and $1\notin I$
$(0)\subseteq I \neq End_{K}(V)$
Now to show that I is both sided ideal we get contradiction.
i am not getting it from my text book

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the basic verification stands between you and the answer:

If the image of $f$ and $g$ are finite dimensional, show that the images of $-f$ and $f+g$ are finite dimensional also.

For any $h\in End_K(V)$, give a reason why $fh$ has finite dimensional image.

Finally, why should the image of $hf$ be finite dimensional?

Comment: How we can prove if $V$ is finite dimensional then $End(V)$ is simple ring ?

Comment: @user197636 You can show it's isomorphic to the full ring of square matrices $M_n(F)$ for some $n$, and then it's simple [for this reason.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/654451/29335)

Comment: 's thanks alot now i will try this.