# $R$ is simple iff $M_n(R)$ is simple for rings without identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, ideals, noncommutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring without identity and $n$ be a positive integer. **Prove that 
the ring $R$ is simple iff $M_n(R)$ is simple.**

When $R$ is unital ring (i.e. with identity) it is easy because we know the structure of two-sided ideals in $M_n(R)$. So we can consider the case, when $R$ is non-unital.

Comment: this question differs from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654451/for-any-ring-a-the-matrix-ring-m-na-is-simple-if-and-only-if-a-is-simple because the last is for unital rings

Comment: What exactly is your definition of simple rings, please?

Comment: $ R $ is simple if $ R^2\neq 0$ and there are no non-trivial two-sided ideals in $ R $.