# Group ring isomorphic to matrix ring

Tags: matrices, ring-theory, group-rings, ring-isomorphism

I want to figure out whether $R$ is isomorphic to $S$, where $R = \mathbb{R}[G]$, where $G = \mathbb{Z}/2  \times \mathbb{Z}/2$, and $S = M_4(\mathbb{R})$.

It seems that they might not be isomorphic, since the obvious isomorphism $\phi \left( \begin{matrix} 
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{matrix}\right) = a(0,0)+b(0,1)+c(1,0)+d(1,1)$ doesn't work because multiplication is not preserved, I think. Am I doing something wrong or are these actually not isomorphic?

Comment: Please excuse me for my ignorance. What is $\mathbb Z/2$? Do you mean $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$? Why is $G$ a multiplicative group?

Comment: @WilliamMcGonagall I interpreted $\mathbb Z/2$ to be $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ so that $G$ is the Klein 4-group.

Comment: @rschwieb Oh, I see. So, the additive group $G$ is viewed as a multiplicative group in the definition of $R$. Thanks so much for the explanation.

Comment: @WilliamMcGonagall Quite frankly, there is no such thing as an "additive group" or "multiplicative group".  "additive/multiplicative" are not adjectives modifying what the group is, but rather they describe _the notation used for the operation_ in the group.  So... there is simply no need to mention that when considering a group ring.

Comment: @rschwieb Yes, I know, but I was confused because I thought the OP was using the multiplication in the *ring* $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ to define $R$, and $(G,\cdot)$ is not a group.

Comment: @WilliamMcGonagall OK, I see your meaning now,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A group ring with a commutative ring and an abelian group is obviously a commutative ring. $M_2(\mathbb R)$ is obviously not a commutative ring.

---

Since a group ring of a nontrivial group is never simple (the augmentation ideal is a nontrivial ideal) a group ring over such a group can never be a matrix ring over a field (which is always simple.)

Comment: Is there a more elementary solution? For example, what if I don't know those facts about simplicity and I don't want to prove them?

Comment: @Wesley Almost certainly not. Simplicity of matrix rings is among the most elementary facts in noncommutative algebra. That you are learning about group rings without knowing that fact is a little alarming. You should probably just go learn about it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/654451/29335) or in any basic book on ring theory.

Comment: Oh wait, yes *facepalm*, in this case there is another way. If the group had not been abelian, I would have stood by my assessment that simplicity was the obvious way to go.

Comment: Right! I don't know how I missed that either. Seems very obvious now. Thanks