# Quotient Ring of $M_n(\mathbb Z)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have an question.

> How can I show that the quotient rings of $M_n(\mathbb Z)$ other than itself have finitely many elements?

If it was division ring instead of $\mathbb{Z}$,  I could say something. But know I don't know how to start.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/654487/589

Comment: Yes, you have a question, and you already started it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3907222/ideal-of-integer-matrix). What have you tried and what is the context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $I$ a non-zero two-sided ideal of $M_n(\Bbb{Z})$ then $\Bbb{Q} I$ is a two sided ideal of $M_n(\Bbb{Q})$ thus the whole it, a $n^2$-dimensional $\Bbb{Q}$-vector space, generated by $n^2$ elements, once multiplied by the right integer they are in $I$ and they generate a finite index sub-$\Bbb{Z}$-module of $M_n(\Bbb{Z})$.