# Is any matrix ring simple?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

A ring $R$ is simple when the only ideals of $R$ are $R$ itself and the trivial $\{0\}$.
A matrix ring is any ring of $n\times n$ matrices where multiplication is the usual matrix multiplication, this ring can be over any ring or field.

Is a matrix ring always simple ? I think it should be simple and I am looking for a rigorous proof.

The following answer assume the ring is unital and is also not related immediately to my question 
[for any ring $A$ the matrix ring $M_n(A)$ is simple if and only if $A$ is simple](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654451/for-any-ring-a-the-matrix-ring-m-na-is-simple-if-and-only-if-a-is-simple)

where when multiplying by elementary matrices we need to check that these matrices are in our 'smaller' ring and not in the bigger $M_n(A)$ ring
A matrix ring can just be a proper subring of $M_n(A)$ for example. Or is it not possible ?

Then what if also our ring is not unital ?

Comment: consider for example the ring of upper triangular matrices over the complex numbers, is it simple ? why?

Comment: The strictly upper triangular matrices form an ideal f the upper triangular matrices.

Comment: Yes indeed, and we can generalize that to nilpotent matrices of any degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are saying a matrix ring to mean "a subring of $M_n(R)$ for some ring $R$ and positive integer $n$".

Clearly not all subrings could be simple.  You could take, for example, the subring consisting of just the matrices which are zero off the diagonal, which is never simple if $n>1$.

Comment: Thank you, can you come up with a counter example for this statement: 
"Let A be a unital Banach algebra, let n be a positive integer, and let $\phi : A \rightarrow M_n$ be a homomorphism of complex algebras, $M_n$ denoting the algebra of all $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{C}$. Show that $\phi$ is continuous " ?
which is clear if we add the assumption that $\phi$ is surjective, I am looking for a counter example if we omit this assumption.